# CGM File support in RenderX

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xml-formatting, renderx

Does RenderX support CGM file formats? Earlier the support for the same is not there. Are there any workarounds to achieve the same?

After few trails we came across a tool called JCGM which generated FO which can be used as in input for RenderX. But the following issue happens while trying it out.

[error] Failed to create image file:/D:/test.cgm of type null
        [error] com.renderx.graphics.ImageFormatException: com.renderx.util.Magic$UnknownMIMETypeException: cannot determine mime type for file 'file:/D:/test.cgm'

**FO file has following lines:**

```
<fo:block id="page.1460112090007da8004b69a" line-height="0"/>
<fo:block keep-together="always" start-indent="0pt">
<fo:external-graphic src="test.cgm"/>
<fo:block padding-top="0pt" padding-bottom="10pt" font-size="10pt" text-align="center" font-style="italic">Figure 1  </fo:block>
```

FO->XEP fails with above error and after generating XEP->PDF, drawing won’t be seen in PDF.

We are using xep-debug.jar for RenderX.
Since, RenderX cannot support CGM graphics format, we are using jcgm-core-0.2.0.jar and jcgm-image-0.1.1.jar for CGM reading/rendering support. Is there any other way to include plugin jars, so that RenderX can use them to render CGM drawings?

Any pointers will be greatly helpful.

Comment: If this is commercial software, why not ask them? http://renderx.com/

Comment: I did post the query over there as well. But thought of asking it to the larger audience. Kindly advise.

Comment: Ah. Just so you know, it is standard practice on the internet to declare [cross-posting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting), to avoid duplication of effort. (As to the question, I've no idea - just trying to direct to to the correct forum).

Comment: Actually even I don't want the precious effort to be wasted twice in two different places as you mentioned, Since I haven't heard from the post in RenderX. At least some references/pointers will help me move ahead. Hence posted. Kindly request you to help me find some directions.